# Broken letter both physical and touch

Tags: windows, laptop

Does anyone know what would cause one letter to not work on the keyboard or the touchscreen as well?

The password requires this letter but it does not register.

Comment: Can you type the letter in programs such as Notepad?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when this happens to me, it is because a modifier key (ctrl, alt, etc..) is currently stuck down on my keyboard, thus causing the letter not to register as I press it.

Try shaking your keyboard around and pressing the modifier keys a few times.